# Can anyone identify this particular intel soc driver

Tags: windows-10, drivers

I have this driver that is showing an error I want to know what application it's from.

[image]

It's intel so figured it might be one of the intel programs on my computer.

[image]

Can you help me identify which program is using that driver, or what is causing the driver to produce an error?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Check under the "Details" tab, and Hardware ID. The top line with PCI\VEN_xxxx and Dev etc (the whole line) can give some idea what the device may be. Google the VEN and DEV number.

Comment: You will want to uninstall (and delete the driver) then scan for hardware changes.

Comment: SOC might be Intel's System-on-a-Chip for the [Intel Compute Stick](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/compute-stick/intel-compute-stick.html). But this is really unlikely to be installed on your computer, and if it is, then you can safely [uninstall the device and its driver package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/install/using-device-manager-to-uninstall-devices-and-driver-packages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, it's from `intel dnx usb driver` which is part of `platform flash tool lite` which I don't use anymore. So I uninstalled it.